# What is the correct formatting for specifying keys in posts?

Tags: support, questions, markdown, design

Currently I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> keys for code formatting. Is there any other elegant style for Stack Overflow posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> key for code formatting? And this is the only key for code formatting. And yes, you can also use `{}` button instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Or you can manually write code inside `<code>` or `<pre>` tag. And yes, you can test formatting in [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/187824).

See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more and advanced markdown related help.

Comment: I didn't know about <kbd> tag. Where is it listed ?

Comment: @PriyankDoshi - See the updated answer.